# Usar Ajax.BeginForm MVC 4 aspx c#

Tags: c#, html, sql, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Soy novato con el `MVC 4` Mi duda es; ¿Como puedo enviar toda la información que capturo el usuario en `HTML` a una función de mi controlador?. Que esa función inserte mis datos `sql server` con el `Ajax.BeginForm` no hay muchos ejemplos ya que la mayoría usan `Razor`

**Codigo C# Controlador**

```js
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using RequerimientosABCusuarios.Models;

namespace RequerimientosABCusuarios.Controllers
{
public class RequerimientoController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Registros()
    {
        return View("Home");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registro()
    {
        //PropiedadesUsu UsuRe = new PropiedadesUsu();
        var constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
        var Conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
        try
        {
            Conn.Open();            
            string sqlconsult = "insert into Registros values('" + Request["solicitud"] + "', '" + Request["nombre"] + "','" + Request["apellido"] + "'," + Request["numero"] + ",'" + Request["fecha"] + "','" + Request["departamento"] + "','" + Request["puesto"] + "','" + Request["hotel"] + "'," +1+ ")";
            var command = new SqlCommand(sqlconsult, Conn);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Conn.Close();
            return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
     
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        
        }       
   }
}
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<RequerimientosABCusuarios.Models.PropiedadesUsu>" %>


      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>

      <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>REQUERIMIENTO DE ALTA-CAMBIOS-BAJA DE USUARIOS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../Script/Validaciones.js"></script>
        <link href="../../Content/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="../../Script/DatosSelect.js"></script>



      </head>

      <body>
        <% using (Ajax.BeginForm( "Registro", "Requerimiento", new AjaxOptions { })) {%>


          <div class="titulo">
            <h1>Requerimiento De Alta-Cambio-Baja De Usuarios</h1>

            <div class="Personal">
              <div class="Datos">
                <label for="solicitud">Solicitud</label>
                <select name="solicitud">
                  <option>Alta</option>
                  <option>Cambio</option>
                  <option>Baja</option>
                </select>

                <label for="nombre">Nombre(s)</label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">

                <label for="numero">Numero De Colaborador</label>
                <input type="text" id="numero" name="numero">

                <label for="departamento">Departamento</label>
                <input type="text" id="departamento" name="departamento">

              </div>

              <div class="Datos2">
                <label for="apellido">Apellidos(s)</label>
                <input type="text" name="apellido">

                <label for="fecha">Fecha De Solicitud</label>
                <input type="date" name="fecha">

                <label for="puesto">Puesto</label>
                <input type="text" name="puesto">
              </div>

              <div class="hoteles"><span></span>
                <label>Hotel - Empresa</label>
                <br />
                <label for="GC"><span>GC</span>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" id="GC">
                <label for="GP"><span>GP</span>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" id="GP">
                <label for="TRP"><span>TRP</span>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" id="TRP">
                <label for="HZLC"><span>HZLC</span>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" id="HZLC">
                <label for="HZVC"><span>HZCV</span>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" id="HZVC">
                <label for="corporativo"><span>Corporativo</span>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hotel" id="corporativo">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="Subtitulo">
            <h1>Accesos-Aplicaciones-Roles</h1>



            <input type="button" onclick="pasar_parametro('NomSistemas','RecSistemas')" value=">" />
            <input type="button" onclick="pasar_parametro('RecSistemas', 'NomSistemas')" value="<" />

          </div>

          <div class="button">
            <input type="submit" class="BtnGuardar" id="BtnGuardar" name="BtnGuardar" />

          </div>


          <% } %>

            
      </body>

      </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bienvenido a la familia de SOes y al mundo del desarrollo de software, por lo que veo, te recomiendo que aprendas `Entity Framework` + `LinQ` (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) ya que te servirá mucho para jugar con las bases de datos pues esta construido en el top de `ADO.net` y trae muchas ventajas (ahorras buena cantidad de tiempo). Por otro lado la `query` que generas es vulnerable a `inyecciones sql`, revisa este enlace https://www.owasp.org para que te expandas en temas de seguridad en la web y el software que construyas tenga mayor seguridad. Encontrarás muy pocos ejemplos sobre `ASP.net View Engine` en comparación a `Razor` debido a que es mucho más limpio, aquí una tabla comparativa: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/aspx-view-engine-vs-razor-view-engine/ y si quieres aprender `Razor` hace un tiempo hice este tutorial, espero te sea de utilidad: http://fredyfx.com/es/Tutorial-Microsoft-WebMatrix-Razor

Y bueno, con respecto a tu código, parece ser que te hace falta determinar las opciones del `Ajax`:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Registro", "Requerimiento", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "ElIDdelFormulario"

}, new { @id="ElIDdelFormulario" }))
```

Finalmente te recomiendo visitar Channel9 (http://channel9.msdn.com) y la `Microsoft Virtual Academy (MVA)` http://mva.microsoft.com donde tienen cursos gratuitos de Full Tecnologias `Microsoft`:  **ASP.net MVC** dictado por profesionales de alto nivel, dichos cursos se encuentran en español e inglés, y si deseas aprender el inglés:  Duolingo (http://www.duolingo.com), Memrise (http://www.memrise.com) y EngVid (http://www.engvid.com).

Hoy en día es tema de organización de tiempos más que de dinero, dale con todo el power 2.0 al desarrollo!